# My Optimus X2 was missing its custom android

Tags: shell

While I was waiting for my new LJ Optimus X2 (P999) mobile I watched a couple of youtube reviews and it always came with extra features to android. But my phone is pretty much vanila android. Is it because of my carrier? Videotron in Quebec.

Features I am missing: From what I could see in videos there was a different keyboard more like the one from Ios. Also some features like taping the side of the phone to move the cursor around. Holding a icon and tilting the phone left and right to move it around. Pretty sure it had extra features everywhere. Also a lot more options in settings then vanilla android.

Comment: What features are you missing?

Comment: @Onik updated my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know (not from US/CA) the P999 is a T-Mobile G2X device with vanilla Android, whereas P990 is LG Optimus 2x. The specs are [mostly similar](http://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3?idPhone1=3888&idPhone2=3598) but there are certain differences, such as the OS customization. Maybe a custom ROM will bring the functionality to the G2X as well.

Comment: I learned of the P999 while getting my phone. The reviews I was checking where all talking about the Optimus X2 wich is 100% what I have.

Comment: Looking at the website you posted I have a LG phone. Not T-Mobile.

Comment: Ok, then I'd suggest either flashing a stock ROM (some info here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1127849) or taking the phone to a repair shop to get flashed under warranty if you'd prefer not to do it yourself.I can't really help with flashing since I've never dealt with LG phones.

Comment: Oh well just got home and looked around on the net. My provider sells this phone as a LG Optimus X2. But looking in the about my phone info I see LG-P999. So I guess I do have a P999.